# Specflow test will never fail

Tags: c#, .net, testing, automated-tests, specflow

I have a `Specflow` integration test which results in data getting added to a database. This could come through very quickly or take some time depending on the size of a message backlog. My step which checks data has been to the database is as follows:

```
[Then(@"the enriched messages are written to the DB")]
public void ThenTheEnrichedMessagesAreThenWrittenToTheDB()
{
    try
    {
        var DbConnectionOptions = new DbConnectionOptions();
        _configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings").Bind(DbConnectionOptions);
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(DbConnectionOptions.HistoryDb);

        myConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select * FROM dbo.Trades WHERE TradeId = 148874",
                                            myConnection);

        int timeout = 1000;
        for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
        {
            using (var reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    reader[reader.GetOrdinal("DealId")].Should().Be("148874");
                }
            }
            Thread.Sleep(timeout);
            timeout = timeout * 2;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("SQL Exception: " + e.ToString());
```

In it I want to poll the db for the test trade. Each time it is polled the timeout should double.

My problem is that this test will never fail. If the test is successful the fluid assertion inside the if will pass but if not it will never reach that in order to fail. If I move it elsewhere the test will likely fail even if the trade is just held up and if I leave it where it is and the trade never reaches the db it will pass as the assert will never be executed. How can I fix this?

Comment: As a general rule a test should never be catching exceptions (unless it's actually testing for the exception). An unhandled exception will cause the test to fail; handling it will not.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `try-catch` block from the step definition. An unhandled exception will fail the test. The test results will display the exception message and stack trace, so there is no need to log it. You will need additional code changes though. With doubling the wait time on each iteration, worse case scenario your test should take no more than 27 seconds (plus query time) to finally fail.

```
[Then(@"the enriched messages are written to the DB")]
public void ThenTheEnrichedMessagesAreThenWrittenToTheDB()
{
    var DbConnectionOptions = new DbConnectionOptions();
    _configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings").Bind(DbConnectionOptions);
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(DbConnectionOptions.HistoryDb);

    myConnection.Open();
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select * FROM dbo.Trades WHERE TradeId = 148874",
                                        myConnection);

    int timeout = 1000;
    int maxAttempts = 13;
    int currentAttempt = 0;

    for (currentAttempt; currentAttempt < maxAttempts; currentAttempt++)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    reader[reader.GetOrdinal("DealId")].Should().Be("148874");
                    break; // Assertion passed, so do not bother checking again.
                }
            }
            Thread.Sleep(timeout);
            timeout = timeout * 2;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Exception thrown when attempting to get DealId: " + ex);
        }
    }

    if (currentAttempt == maxAttempts)
    {
        throw new TimeoutException("Timed out checking TradeId 148874");
    }
}
```

The `try-catch` block should just wrap the attempt to query the database. If an exception gets thrown, you can still log the exception for debugging purposes. Only after exceeding the max number of attempts should you throw a `TimeoutException` which will cause the test to fail. *This exception should be unhandled.* The last major change is if your assertion for the `DealId` passes, break out of the loop. No sense in waiting the timeout period if you already asserted the DealId is correct.